# How to cancel pipeline -- No cancel button is available

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline running (8735cc10-80db-4401-8f9e-516d733b450e). From the activity runs page, I see the pipeline is running, but from the Pipleline Runs page, it shows a status of failure.

Is there a way to cancel this pipeline run from the UI ?

Comment: If you hover over the pipeline name, you will see the cancel button. It might not be available when you asked the question but it is available as of today

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is from powershell.

Download the Azure sdk for powershell from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/ then run this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "SubscName"

Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName "Name" -DataFactoryName "DataFactoryName" -PipelineRunId 8735cc10-80db-4401-8f9e-516d733b450e
```

Replace with your own names.

Hope this helped!